# How to remove the highlighting from the gridview column header when cell selected in gridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I when i click on any cell in the gridView i found the column header higlighed like this.

[image]

How to remove this?

I tried to find the properity that change this.
I changed the style of the column header by this:

```
dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

But I couldn't find any such thing for the selection.